# Although it works in css on other pages, it doesn't work on the category page (Django)

Tags: python, html, css, django

I built a blog site. Although it works in css on other pages, it doesn't work on the category page. What can I do? I edited. thanks for your answers. It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
Here is my code:

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
```

blog/views.py

```
def category_detail(request, cats):
    category_posts=Blog.objects.filter(category_id=cats)
    context = {
        'cats': cats, 'category_posts': category_posts,
    }
    return render(request, 'post/category.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import include, path

from blog.views import blog_detail, category_detail
from home.views import home_view, about_view
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^adminerdo/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home_view),
    url(r'^about/$', about_view),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', blog_detail , name= 'detay'),
    url(r'^category/(?P<cats>[\w-]+)/$', category_detail, name='category'),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

category.html

```
{% include 'header2.html' %}

    <div class="blog_breadcrumb_wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <div class="blog_breadcrumb_div">
                        <h3>{{ blog.title }}</h3>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog_main_wrapper blog_toppadder60 blog_bottompadder60">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                    <div class="blog_post_style2 blog_single_div">
                        <div class="blog_post_style2_img wow fadeInUp">
                            <img src="{{ blog.image.url}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="blog_post_style2_content wow fadeInUp">
                            <h3>{{ blog.title }}</h3>
                            <div class="blog_author_data"><a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/34x34" class="img-fluid" alt="" width="34" height="34"> {{ blog.user}}</a></div>
                         {{ cats }}
{% for blog in category_posts %}
    {{ blog.category }}
    {{ blog.title }}
{% endfor %}


                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

header2.html --- detail.html is working with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html lang="en" class="ie8 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html lang="en" class="ie9 no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html lang="tr">
<!--<![endif]-->
<!-- Begin Head -->

<head>
    <title>tittle</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <meta name="description" content="Blog">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="kamleshyadav">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <!--Start Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/js/plugins/swiper/swiper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/js/plugins/magnific/magnific-popup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css">
    <!-- Favicon Link -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../static/images/favicon.png">
</head>
```

I edited. thanks for your answers. It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

when your `settings` say:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
```

Try:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**EDIT after OP update:**

So, you've set up django's static handling system, but you're not using it.  Try:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css" />
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for answer but didn't work. index, about and blog_detail are working with css. But only category page is problem. category.html is same blog_detail page.

Comment: i added category.html and header2.html <head>

Comment: see edited answer.  You are not using django's static handling properly:  https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files